# ASP.Net Treeview+Grid control

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a requirement to create n-tiered type grid with the ability to expand rows.  First thought was the Treeview control as you can dynamically add to a node easily but you can only have one text value.  Does anyone know of a tree/grid control that exists?

Or can anyone suggest an alternative to this route?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Telerik TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)?

Comment: Preferably something that won't cost money